# Sending picture to TcpClient in VB

Tags: vb.net, image, tcpclient

I am relatively new to Visual Basic. Currently working on visual studio 2005. I have an application that sends text message to a client (on our domain) using TcpClient in Visual Basic. As far as text is concerned, I can send it with ease and the client receives it. However, I am intending to send pictures to the client and force them to save at a specific location. Any suggestions regarding how to do this in VB. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the picture into a byte array, send the byte array and then save the byte array to file at the other end. Some (untested) sample code from [this site](http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/image-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to.html) to do the conversion:

```
Private Function BytesToImage(ByVal ImageBytes() As Byte) As Image
    Dim imgNew As Image
    Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ImageBytes)
    imgNew = Image.FromStream(memImage)
    Return imgNew
End Function

Private Function ImageToBytes(ByVal Image As Image) As Byte()
    Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim bytImage() As Byte

    Image.Save(memImage, Image.RawFormat)
    bytImage = memImage.GetBuffer()

    Return bytImage
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it and get back to you with the results.